# how to access a worker thread from UI thread?

Tags: multithreading, xaml, c++-cx, worker, ui-thread

I have a working thread running all along the runtime, who generates events.

I can handle those events inside the UI thread by using `disp = Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread()->Dispatcher`.

more precisely, I do the modifications to the UI by using `disp->RunAsync(...)` anywhere inside the working thread.

but I don't know how to do the inverted operation. I want to have some Async function inside the UI thread to perform operation (on some `std::unique_ptr`) in the working thread when I click on some button.

Comment: The UI thread is special, it has a dispatcher that solves the [producer-consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem).  Which allows you to run code on that thread.  If you want to do this on a worker thread as well then you need to solve that same problem.  A thread-safe queue is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to be able to run an async operation when a button is clicked, but on a specific thread to which you refer as your worker thread.

First - Since you want to use a resource in 2 threads you should not use `unique_ptr` and use `shared_ptr` since you share this resource between the two threads.

Second - if you don't necessarily have to run the action on a specific thread then you can simply use [Windows::System::Threading::ThreadPool::RunAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230595.aspx) and capture the `shared_ptr` **by value.**

e.g:

```
namespace WST = Windows::System::Threading;

WST::ThreadPool::RunAsync(
    ref new WST::WorkItemHandler(
            [mySharedPtr](Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction^ operation)
            {
                mySharedPtr->Foo();
            }));
```

In case you have to run the operation on a specific thread then I assume you want to be able to append operations to an already running thread, otherwise you are creating a thread and you can use the above example.
So in order to append operations to an already running thread, that thread must have the functionality of getting a new operations and then running those operations in a synchronous order. This functionality is basically what the Dispatcher provides. This is what an [Event Loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) is, also called: message dispatcher, message loop, message pump, or run loop. Also you can find information by reading on the Recator\Proactor design pattern.

[This CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33011/Proactor-Pattern) page shows one way of implementing the pattern, and you can use Winrt component to make it better \ more conveniant \ more familiar

Comment: actually I use only one work thread, I solved the problem by using a queue list of orders. Orders are send from the UI thread and executed in the work thread.